# How does an action in react redux actually work?

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I'm quite new to this redux stuff so basic stuff like this still confuses me a lot.

Here's how I've been told to structure my action function in react redux like this

```
const load_user = () => async dispatch => {
dispatch({...})
}
```

and I connect this function to my component via react redux `connect` helper.

so my question regarding this function is

1. Where did the `dispatch` in that action function came from?
2. Why do you need to return a function instead of calling the dispatch in the first function?

thank you very much!

Comment: First of all you probably aren't using just redux. There are some things to separate out: (a) `connect` is provided by `react-redux` which is a helper lib for using redux with react (b) the ability to return functions as actions comes from redux middleware such as `redux-thunk` and it is not basic redux.

Comment: It would really help you clarify things if you (a) try a basic **redux** app on its own to see what can be done. (b) Read about the react [contex](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) API which is how `react-redux` passes the the state and dispatch to child components (c) Read how [middleware](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#middleware)  works keeping in mind that this is how `redux-think` augments the basic redux functionality and handles actions when they are themselves functions

Answer (score 1):

What you are writing here is a thunk action creator, not a normal action creator, and a good indicator that the tutorial teaching you this has kinda understood Redux, but got some of the concepts a bit wrong.

A normal action creator would look like

```js
const load_user = () => {
  return {...}
}
```

and for this simple use case be 100% equal in functionality, less code and what you should do instead.

A thunk on the other hand is a function that is being dispatched, and everytime you dispatch a function to Redux, the thunk middleware executes that function with (dispatch, getState) as arguments. That's why that is working too, but should not be used in that simple use case. You can find more about thunks here: https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks

That said, in modern Redux you should not be writing normal action creators at all, as those are auto-generated for you. Your tutorial is likely teaching you a very outdated style of Redux. Modern Redux does not use switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPES, hand-written action creators, immutable reducer logic or `connect`. Please see the official Redux tutorial at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts instead.

Answer (score 0):

Redux actions can only be object, preferably object literals with no prototype values so it can be serialized .

You can add [middleware](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#middleware) if your actions are anything but serializable objects.

In your example the [thunk middleware](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) is used and the simplest implementation of that looks like this:

```
const thunkMiddleware =
  ({ getState, dispatch }) =>
  (next) =>
  (action) =>
    typeof action === 'function'
      // dispatch and getstate come from here
      ? action(dispatch,getState)
      : next(action);
```

Answer (score 0):

Making an explanation out of your example

```js
const load_user = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({...})
}
```

Answer for Q1, `dispatch` is there only because your `redux` hooked up with `redux-thunk`

Any "normal/typical" redux action, without `redux-thunk`, will only need to return an object like below

```js
const load_user = () => ({ type: 'xxx', payload: 'yyy' })
```

Answer for Q2, why do we need `dispatch` instead of returning object, simply because `load_user` is a complex action that will need to "return" multiple time

```js
const load_user = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: LOADING_USER })

  const response = await fireServerToLoadUser(); //API call sample;

  if (response.data) {
     dispatch({ type: LOAD_SUCCESS })
  } else {
     dispatch({ type: LOAD_FAILED })
  }
}
```

As you can see from above, `load_user` will need to "return" at least two type of object, one is `{type: loading_user}` and another is success or failed depending on situation.